# How to find out new pages / lists / listitems added to the intranet site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to find what new pages / lists / listitems have been added to the intranet site and generate a report on daily basis ?

We have to implement this on sharepoint 2010 and also on sharepoint 2013 websites. We are using C#.NET. I am aware that we can find newly created listitems by creating a listview and then sorting it by DATE as TODAY-2 where 2 is no. of days prior. But, how can I implement same for all lists in the site? I am doing research on the web analytics in sharepoint 2010, but this doesnot seem to serve my purpose.

Have you come across similar requirement?

Comment: You can use powershell to itterate your sites and lists or use search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **sharepoint audit logs**. Enable the auditing functionality for the list and libraries or for the entire site. The following links will help with the same:

[Enable auditing 1](http://davecoleman146.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[Enable auditing 2](http://sharepointthomas.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in.html)

[View audit log reports](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx)
[Write custom entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466221(v=office.12).aspx)

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditeventtype.aspx)